# Only show <li> when content added via custom field

Tags: custom-field

I've gone through a few of the other similar topics but any of the solutions won't work for me.

Basically I only want to show an

if the custom field has had information added into it.

Here's my code, even if you don't give me an answer could you point me in the correct direction as to how to do this.

```
<div class="height">
<div class="fourcol">
<p class="business"><?php the_field('helpline_name'); ?></p>                                                       <div class="category"><p>AREAS OF HELP: <?php the_category(', ') ?></p> </div>
                                            <p><?php the_field('helpline_address'); ?></p>
</div>
<div class="fivecol">
<p class="phone"><?php the_field('helpline_phone_number'); ?></p>
                                                   </div>                       
<div class="threecol last">
                                              <ul>
                                            <li><a href="http://<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>" class="tiptip web" title="<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="" class="tiptip comments" title="read comments from others" target="_blank"><?php echo the_field('helpline_comments'); ?></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo the_field('helpline_email'); ?>" class="tiptip email" title="email us your problem"><?php echo the_field('helpline_email'); ?></a></li>
                                        </ul>
```

Thanks in advance
Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a **PHP** question than a **WordPress** question. But, based on this example code:

```
<li><a href="http://<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>" class="tiptip web" title="<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?></a></li>
```

...it appears that the `the_field()` function *returns* a value (since you then *echo* that returned value. Thus, simply wrap the entire `<li>` output in a conditional, using `the_field()`:

```
<?php
if ( the_field( 'helpline_url' ) ) {
    ?>
    <li><a href="http://<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>" class="tiptip web" title="<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Chris that worked like a treat! For any listings now that don't have a website assigned it doesn't show it.

Only thing I need to do now is do some playing with the css!

Answer (score 1):

I'd wrap the output in a conditional statement like this.

```
<?php if( empty(the_field('helpline_url')) ) : ?>  

<li>
<a href="http://<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>" 
class="tiptip web" title="<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>" 
target="_blank">
<?php echo the_field('helpline_url'); ?>
</a>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which basically translates to:

1. Check if `the_field('helpline_url')` is empty.
2. If it isn't empty, then do comes after `:` *(which is the html that generates the list item)*

There could be typos and spelling errors or whatnot so please triplecheck and make sure I haven't made a mistake, but this is the structure of code you're looking for.